# Start_time for adset

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I can't set `starting_time` for the adset.
When adset is created, the start date is:

> [start_time] => 2016-06-31T13:00:00+0600

which means the date has been generated by my code.
But then, when I read adset by `id` or observe it in ads manager, the `start_date` **turns to creation date** (today's one).

Has anyone faced this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.

but June doesn't have 31th... that's why facebook ignored that input